# Cant get CSS property from child?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have this HTML code here :

```
 <div id="ctr" class="faden-slider-container">
    <div class="conteneur-image" ></div>
    <div class="conteneur-image" ></div>
    <div class="conteneur-image" ></div>
</div>
```

And I am trying to get the CSS property of the second div which class' name is `conteneur-image` but I get nothing :

```
app.controller("slideCtrl",function ($scope) {
    alert("hello")

    var tab = new Array();
    var elements = new Array();

    for(var i = 0; i<3 ; i++){
        elements[i] = document.getElementById("ctr").children[i]
    }

    var style = window.getComputedStyle(elements[1])
    var message = style.getPropertyCSSValue("background").cssText()

    alert("CSS Value is  : "+message)
})
```

Comment: `id` is not a valid css property value.

Comment: which property value do you want to access?

Comment: `getPropertyCSSValue` is obsolete (since 2003) and should not be used. And even when it wasn't obsolete, it could not be used to retrieve the values of shorthand properties such as `background`.

Comment: @gurvinder372 Yes "id" is not a CssProperty, just a mistake, i edited  it, i want to get the background

Comment: @TaouBen check the answer

Comment: @Mr Lister : i have used it this morning and it worked perfecly fine, thanks for this information :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of issues there.

- [getPropertyCSSValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyCSSValue) is obsolete and may not work in browsers anymore
- `id` is a selector, not a valid css property

Use [getPropertyValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue) instead,

```
var message = style.getPropertyCSSValue("background");
```

**Demo**

```js
var style = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("ctr").children[1])
var message = style.getPropertyValue("background");

console.log("CSS Value is  : " + message)
```

```html
<div id="ctr" class="faden-slider-container">
  <div class="conteneur-image"></div>
  <div class="conteneur-image"></div>
  <div class="conteneur-image"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello! Well it shows CSS Value is undefined .. i dont know why ? Thank for you answer mate

Comment: Which browser and version?

Comment: I am using Firefow the latest version .. now it works .. Thank you so much for your time friend

Answer (score 2):

Using `jquery`,you can get your 2nd HTML element this way:

```
var element = $("#ctr").children().eq(1);
```

Then if you want to make some transformation, like applying style:

```
element.css("background-color", "blue")
```

Here is a snippet:

```js
var element = $("#ctr").children().eq(1);

    element.css("background-color", "blue")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ctr" class="faden-slider-container">
    <div class="conteneur-image" >one</div>
    <div class="conteneur-image" >second</div>
    <div class="conteneur-image" >third</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello friend, i am trying to avoid jquery now and use only javascript or angulars methods only. Thank you for your help